# PHP pass additional parameters to callback function

Tags: php

Is there a way to pass additional parameters to a callback function?

```
class Bar{

  public function test(){
      $count = 0; 

      $foo = new Class();
      $foo->calling([$this, 'barFunction']);
  }

  public function barFunction($data, $count){
      //...
  }
```

I want Foo's calling method to pass data in and to also pass $count as the second parameter.

Here is an example with a closure instead of a parameter. If I use a closure I can pass $count in but in this case I need to use Bar's class function.

```
class Bar{

  public function test(){
      $count = 0; 

      $foo = new Class();
      $foo->calling(function($data) use($count){
         //..some work
      });
  }
```

Comment: I don't really see through what you want to do? Should that be pseudo code above or what does `calling` looks like?

Comment: I added an example of what I want to achieve with a closure but how would I do it by using a class method instead.

Answer (score 4):

Could use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

`call_user_func_array([$context, $function], $params);`

i.e. in your example, `$context` would be Bar (`$this`), `$function` would be your `'barFunction'`, and the params would be `[$data, $count]`.

Like this?

```
<?php 

class Foo {
    public function __construct() {}

    public function mDo($callback) {
        $count = 10;
        $data = ['a', 'b'];

        // do a lot of work (BLOCKING)

        call_user_func_array($callback, [$data, $count]);
    }
}

class Bar {
    public function test() {
        $a = new Foo();
        $a->mDo([$this, 'callback']);
    }

    public function callback($data, $count) {
        print($data);
        print($count);
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->test();
```

Comment: Would $data be defined since calling() is providing it?

Comment: @Tom I provided a complete example

Comment: That would work but I can't edit mDo method. I provided an example of what I want to achieve using a closure but I need to use the class method instead.

Comment: Seemed like overkill for my use case.

Comment: I don't see why you need to use reflection - seems like overkill.

Answer (score 3):

OOP is your friend. Declare the callback as a class:

```
class BarCallback {
    private $count;

    public function __construct($count) {
        $this->count = $count;
    }

    public function callback($data) {
        // do work here
    }
}
```

And then `Bar` would look something like this:

```
class Bar {
  public function test() {
      $count = 0; 

      $foo = new Class();
      $bar_cb = new BarCallback($count);
      $foo->calling([$bar_cb, 'callback']);
  }
}
```

Does that help?